# my nft image not showing in opensea testnet

Tags: nft, erc-721, ipfs, opensea, meta-data

when ever i mint an nft with my frontend dapp and check it on opensea i will just see the name without the nft image.
here is my deploy.js file. this is the tutorial i am following https://dev.to/rounakbanik/writing-an-nft-collectible-smart-contract-2nh8

````
async function main() {
    const baseTokenURI = "ipfs://QmfQHRsTrFN9tHVjsZ3aM2L225aUxk73LX2fFFa2GEPZ9y/";

    // Get owner/deployer's wallet address
    const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    // Get contract that we want to deploy
    const contractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("AnezichukwuNFT");

    // Deploy contract with the correct constructor arguments
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(baseTokenURI);

    // Wait for this transaction to be mined
    await contract.deployed();

    // Get contract address
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", contract.address);

    // Reserve NFTs
    let txn = await contract.reserveNFTs();
    await txn.wait();
    console.log("5 NFTs have been reserved");

    // Mint 3 NFTs by sending 0.003 ether
    txn = await contract.mintNFTs(3, { value: utils.parseEther('0.003') });
    await txn.wait()

    // Get all token IDs of the owner
    let tokens = await contract.tokensOfOwner(owner.address)
    console.log("Owner has tokens: ", tokens);

}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }); ```
````

Comment: i too have similar problem. I recently, deployed a smart contract from remix ide to opensea, but encountred a problem. Problem:
Images are not loading on opensea testnet. contract adress:
(https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x39F817A5C50C1A0616efCc00CAb152FA0EbbEF0A#readContract) opensea testnet: https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/mumbai/0x39f817a5c50c1a0616efcc00cab152fa0ebbef0a/2

Answer (score 2):

In metadata, you gave image attribute the **wrong value** (x.png). If you want Opensea to find your image you should provide a public uri to your image as the value.

Usually you first upload the image to ipfs and then add the ipfs uri to the image tag like so "image": "ipfs://QmfQHRsTrFN9tHVjsZ3aM2L225aUxk73LX2xxxxxxxxxx"