# reason: 'execution reverted: Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.', code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',

Tags: solidity, hardhat, alchemy, sepolia

I am attempting to deploy a smart contract to the Sepolia testnet. I currently have ~1 Sepolia eth in my wallet. I am using Hardhat and Alchemy and I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/scrappy-squirrels/tutorial-writing-an-nft-collectible-smart-contract-9c7e235e96da) Here is my code for hardhat.config.js :

```
require('dotenv').config();
require("hardhat-deploy");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: API_URL,
    accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
};
```

Here is my run.js:

```
async function main() {
    const baseTokenURI = "ipfs://QmemE2wZKkf8Y9FPufzxRbnoF1VtB17FvRSkn7f2ve2wY5/";

    // Get owner/deployer's wallet address
    const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    // Get contract that we want to deploy
    const contractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTCollectible");

    // Deploy contract with the correct constructor arguments
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(baseTokenURI);

    // Wait for this transaction to be mined
    await contract.deployed();

    // Get contract address
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", contract.address);

    // Reserve NFTs
    let txn = await contract.reserveNFTs();
    await txn.wait();
    console.log("3 NFTs have been reserved");

    // Mint 1 NFTs by sending 0.01 ether
    txn = await contract.mintNFTs(3, { value: utils.parseEther('0.01') });
    await txn.wait()

    // Get all token IDs of the owner
    let tokens = await contract.tokensOfOwner(owner.address)
    console.log("Owner has tokens: ", tokens);

}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Here is my contract.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;



import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";


contract NFTCollectible is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    uint public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 50;
    uint public constant PRICE = 0.01 ether;
    uint public constant MAX_PER_MINT = 3;
    
    string public baseTokenURI;
    


constructor(string memory baseURI) ERC721("NFT Collectible", "NFTC"){
setBaseURI(baseURI);
}

function reserveNFTs() public onlyOwner {
uint totalMinted = _tokenIds.current();

require(
    totalMinted.add(3) < MAX_SUPPLY, "Not enough NFTs"
);
for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++){
_mintSingleNFT();
}
}

function _baseURI() internal
                    view
                    virtual
                    override
                    returns (string memory) {
            return baseTokenURI;
}

function setBaseURI(string memory _baseTokenURI) public onlyOwner{
baseTokenURI = _baseTokenURI;
}

function mintNFTs(uint _count) public payable{
    uint totalMinted = _tokenIds.current();
    
    require(
        totalMinted.add(_count) <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Not enough NFTs!"
    );
    require(
        _count >0 && _count <= MAX_PER_MINT,
        "Cannot mint specified number of NFTs(Please enter a valid amount)."
    );
    require(
    msg.value >= PRICE.mul(_count), "Not enough ether to purchase NFTs."
    );
     for (uint i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
            _mintSingleNFT();
     }}
     
     function _mintSingleNFT() private{
     uint newTokenID = _tokenIds.current();
     _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenID);
     _tokenIds.increment();
     }
     
     function tokenOfOwner(address _owner)
            external
            view
            returns (uint[] memory){
            
        uint tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint[] memory tokensId = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        
        for (uint i = 0; i < tokenCount; i++){
        tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokensId;
            }
            
            
function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    uint balance = address(this).balance;
    require(balance > 0, "No ether left to withdraw.");
    
    (bool success, ) =(msg.sender).call{value: balance}("");
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");
}

}
```

.env has my alchemy URL and my private key. When I run

```
enpx hardhat run scripts/run.js --network sepolia
```

it throws this error:

```
Contract deployed to: 0x1234567890qwerty1234567890qwerty
3 NFTs have been reserved
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x1234567890qwerty1234567890qwerty","to":"0x1234567890qwerty1234567890qwerty","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x2386f26fc10000"},"data":"0x3b4b13810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003","accessList":null}, error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: execution reverted: Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\\Users\\john\\nft-collectible\\node_modules\\hardhat\\src\\internal\\core\\providers\\http.ts:88:21)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\\Users\\john\\nft-collectible\\node_modules\\@nomiclabs\\hardhat-ethers\\src\\internal\\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)","code":3,"_isProviderError":true,"data":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000224e6f7420656e6f75676820657468657220746f207075726368617365204e4654732e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:78:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:642:20)
    at step (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'execution reverted: Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x1234567890qwerty1234567890qwerty',
    to: '0x1234567890qwerty1234567890qwerty',
    value: BigNumber { value: "10000000000000000" },
    data: '0x3b4b13810000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003',
    accessList: null
  },
  error: ProviderError: execution reverted: Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.
      at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:88:21)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\Users\john\nft-collectible\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
}
```

Comment: show run script please. and the related functions in contract

Comment: @MajdTL I have added in the code you requested.

Comment: you are minting 3 NTFs but sending only the price of 1 . change this line to: txn = await contract.mintNFTs(3, { value: utils.parseEther('0.03') });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Price of 1 NFT is hardcoded to 0.01Ether `uint public constant PRICE = 0.01 ether;`

But when you are buying/minting the NFTs, you are buying 3 and sending only the required ether for 1 ->
`txn = await contract.mintNFTs(3, { value: utils.parseEther('0.01') });`

This will trigger this error:

`require(msg.value >= PRICE.mul(_count), "Not enough ether to purchase NFTs.");`

You need either to send 0.03 Ether with your transaction

`txn = await contract.mintNFTs(3, { value: utils.parseEther('0.03') });`

Or mint only 1 NFT with value: 0.01

`txn = await contract.mintNFTs(1, { value: utils.parseEther('0.01') });`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. As a follow up question, my tutorial said that I would now be able to see my NFT transaction on Etherscan (I was), and that I would be able to find them on OpenSeaTestnet if I searched for the contract address. I was not. Do you know why this is happening? I also tried to search for their contract address, which is `0x355638a4eCcb777794257f22f50c289d4189F245` But that didn't return any results either. I am searching for the wrong thing?

Comment: @That_Coder weird, are you sure you are using the correct API_URL and can you post the address of the account you use to deploy? and is it your account or have you found the private key somewhere in the tutorial?

Comment: No, it's my account. I can see it on Etherscan, and I have put in my API_URL. When I call the withdraw method from Etherscan the funds from the contract go into my wallet. This is my account address: `0xe7eE00Cb67c3eB80937669f593A9FF3a4d3e96b2` Also, I don't know if the testnet matters, but I'm on Sepolia.

Comment: @NalLuksic Could you please clarify what you mean in this post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143161/my-nft-image-not-showing-in-opensea-testnet                                   I am currently having the same issue(using the same tutorial). Thanks!

Comment: @That_Coder the metadata of your NFT has no valid image URL. for example the metadata of NFT with Id = 1 can be found on IPFS -> https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfQHRsTrFN9tHVjsZ3aM2L225aUxk73LX2fFFa2GEPZ9y/1.json . If you check the image property you see only "1.png". 1.png is like only a placeholder and it must be a valid URL. So you need to upload your own metadata to IPFS or a public server and use your own "baseTokenURI"

Comment: Hey! I finally found out what it was! OpenseaTestnet only supports the Goerli network, so when I redeployed my contract with Goerli, there it was. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: wow rly.. weird, then the ipfs link in the question, is not the same you are using?

Comment: No, my JSON data has a valid IPFS URL. Thanks. I don't know if you do anything with React, but I'm having an isssue with my NFT [frontend](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147555/ethers-is-not-defined-no-undef). Thanks.

Comment: @That_Coder sadly not but check this https://programmablewealth.com/ethersjs-react-tutorial/